# remove slash added by history.pushState from url

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i need to remove unwanted "/" from url when using `history.pushStat` to add query params in vuejs

my vuejs method

```
export default {
    name: "Home",
    metaInfo: {
        title: "صفحه اصلی"
    },
    data() {
        return {
            files: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        type(file) {
            if (file.membership && file.price)
                return `${file.membership.name},نقدی`
            if (file.price)
                return "نقدی";
            if (file.membership)
                return file.membership.name
        },
        getFiles(page=1){
            let queries=this.$route.query;
            queries.page=page
            axios.get(`/api/files`,{
                params:queries
            })
                .then(({data}) => {
                    this.files = data;
                    window.history.pushState(null,'home',"?"+data.meta.queries) // queries add in this line

                })
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.getFiles(this.$route.query.page)
    }
}
```

url after adding queries

`http://localhost:8000/?page=1`

i would like to remove "slash" to be like `http://localhost:8000?page=1`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `this.$router.push` instead of `window.history.pushState` :

```
 this.$router.push({ path: '/', query: { page:1 } })
```

Comment: Even better, use named routes instead of paths.

Comment: uncaught (in promise) NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/".